# How do I calculate the number of addressable words in memory?

Tags: memory, memory-management, cpu-architecture

I was reading through last years computer architecture exam paper and came across this question:

Main Memory consists of 32 MB, with each byte directly addressable by 16 bit address.

a. Calculate the number of addressable words in this memory.

b. Suppose this memory is divided into fixed length of 64 words each
How many blocks are in this memory?

I'll probably end up asking my professor/classmates to assist me with this, but just thought that this would be a good place to ask to find different & maybe even easy approaches to solving this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are 2 possible ambiguities: is it 32000000 bytes (32MB), or `32 * 1024*1024` bytes (32 MiB)?  And does the machine have 8-bit bytes?  And one major unknown: what is the word-size?  Also, 16 bits isn't a wide enough address for that amount of memory.

Comment: The question would make *much* more sense if you had 16-bit words (with unspecified address width).  Then it's just a trivial math problem of dividing by 2, assuming 8-bit bytes.  You probably read it wrong.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm just going to assume its 32MB instead of MiB because that's exactly how its written on the paper. I typed the questions out word for word exactly as was written on the exam paper.

Comment: The problem is that many people mean `2^20` when they write `MB` as a unit for computer memory.  It would be extremely unusual to have `32 * 10^6` bytes, leaving some combination of address bits invalid.  If I had to pick one assumption, I'd pick that MB = MiB here.

Comment: Alright, so let’s say that it’s most likely 32 MiB as opposed to 32 MB. From here how would you go about solving the question? (I’ll also give it a try in the meantime using MiB instead)

Comment: Well like I said, if we assume you mistyped the question and it's actually 16-bit word size, not 16-bit addresses, then a word is 2 bytes and `32*2^20 / 2 = 16 * 2^20`, obviously.  Otherwise we don't know the word size.  Oh also, should the number of addressable words only be *aligned* words?  Or do they want you to count every valid address for an unaligned word load?  i.e. every byte address except the highest one, or maybe that too if the architecture allows a load from `0xFFFF` to wrap around and take its other byte from `0x0000`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer & I'm sorry for my late reply, it was nighttime here. Got word back from my prof and he said that in this case (and for the majority of our course) we are only working with MB instead of MiB. And instead of 16-bit addresses I should've said that the length of an address is 16-bits, meaning there are 2^16 = 65,536 different addresses. So now when we divide 32 MB (32000000 bytes) with 65,536 (number of addresses) we get 488 bytes (size of the word). So now I think the memory can contain 65,536 words as long as the size of the word doesn't go over 488 bytes.

Comment: Also I'm not sure whether the number of addressable words should only be aligned or unaligned.

Comment: No, the question says the memory is byte-addressable.  Each byte has its own address, so we can't conclude an insane / implausible word-size like 488 bytes.  And only 64kB of your memory is addressable at all with a 16-bit address.  Maybe there's a segmentation mechanism that lets different processes use different 64kB blocks of memory at the same time?

Comment: I think that in this case, like you said earlier, it’s just a trivial math problem with both question A & B each counting for 6 marks.

Comment: What is a word? In the days of 14 and 36 bit computers, there were "words" of 14 and 36 bits? Some assembly languages refer to words as being an integer of some number of bytes. Sadly, this question appears to reflect the typical academic nonsense that transforms simple concepts into complex problems.